# Cosmos DB query syntax WHERE clause with array in array

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The following json represents two documents in a Cosmos DB container.
How can I write a query that gets any document that has an `item` with an `id` of `item_1` and value of `bar`.

I've looked into `ARRAY_CONTAINS`, but don't get this to work with array's in array's.
Als I've tried somethings with `any`. Although I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use this, `any` seems to be a valid function, as I do get [formatting highlights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGJ4o.png) in the cosmos db explorer in Azure Portal.
For the `any` function I tried things like `SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.pages.any(p, p.items.any(i, i.id = "item_1" AND i.value = "bar"))`.

The id fields are unique so if it's easier to find any document that contains any object with the right id and value, that would be fine too.

```
[
  {
    "type": "form",
    "id": "form_a",
    "pages": [
      {
        "name": "Page 1",
        "id": "page_1",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "item_1",
            "value": "foo"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "type": "form",
    "id": "form_b",
    "pages": [
      {
        "name": "Page 1",
        "id": "page_1",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "item_1",
            "value": "bar"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `join` could handle with `WHERE clause with array in array`.Please test below sql:

```
SELECT c.id FROM c
join pages in c.pages
where array_contains(pages.items,{"id": "item_1","value": "bar"},true)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Any chance to get (`SELECT`) the whole document bij doing something like `SELECT c.* FROM c join pages in c.pages ...`?

Comment: @markbeij Well,you can't use `c.*` with `join`.However, you could use `select c.A,c.B,c.C from .....` to cover all your columns. Maybe kind of trouble but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I’m trying to keep my solution as generic as possible.